# Using trickle to limit the bandwidth of a VirtualBox VM

Tags: bandwidth

I'm trying to limit the bandwidth of a virtual machine running via VirtualBox.

`trickle -d 5 virtualbox` doesn't work, I believe because of an issue with child processes
(`trickle -d 5 sudo apt-get upgrade` doesn't work either)

How can I limit the download/upload bandwidth of VirtualBox's VMs?

Comment: also look at (search for) answers here using wondershaper or tc

Answer (score 4):

VirtualBox has bandwidth limiting that you can enable via VboxManage.
See http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bandwidth_limit

> Limits are configured through VBoxManage. The example below creates a
>   bandwidth group named "Limit", sets the limit to 20 Mbit/s and assigns
>   the group to the first and second adapters of the VM:
>
> ```
>    VBoxManage bandwidthctl "VM name" add Limit --type network --limit 20m
>    VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --nicbandwidthgroup1 Limit
>    VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --nicbandwidthgroup2 Limit
> ```

Comment: for me adding these clauses stopped genymotion emulators to work. Network speed control remains one of their paid feature. Do I smell a rat here :p